# Can WAMPServer running on windows 10 handle high traffic?

Tags: php, mysql, server, wamp, wampserver

I am working on an IoT project in which several sensors will send data to my Wamp server through internet and I will log that data in my database.

My question is, can Apache + mySql handle data of these dimension.
There are nearly 800 data coming from sensor over different URL to my server.
Those data needs to be inserted in different table of database.

Now these 800 data comes with frequency of about 5 sec. Data will come 24*7. So on average I will need to fire 800-900 queries every 5 sec.

Would wamp and sql be sufficient to handle these density of data? If not what other server should I use? Or would I need to install some server OS instead of windows?

My PC specs - intel core i7, 16gb ram, 2gb nvidia 1080 graphics

Comment: You say - It's a server. So why don't you just use a "server OS"?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Can you suggest a good one? But free. Windows Server is paid. I don't want to purchase os just for a project.

Comment: `phpmyadmin` is a tool written in PHP its got nothing to do with this senario

Comment: Do you mean you will have 800 devices sending data all at the same time

Comment: Yes and No. Sometimes they will send at same time. Sometime at different time. Like temperature sensor sends data every five seconds. But Viscosity sensor will send every 2-5 min and so on. But there will come time when their send time intersects.

Comment: And you want to use WAMPServer on a Window 10 box as the server for the LIVE system, or just to test the app as you build it

Comment: If it can work on WIndows 10 Home then I will use it for live system. If it can't I will have to switch to server OS. That's what I want to know. If anyone have any experience with high traffic use of Wamp on WIndows 10.

Comment: I already gave you that answer then

Comment: You might try a linux distro on that same PC

Comment: http://www.wampserver.com/en/ says "WampServer is a Windows web **development environment**".

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you suggest , which would be able to handle the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO!

But that is not WAMPServers fault.

Windows 10 itself can only handle about 20 remove connections, as Windows itself uses some of the max 30 that are allowed.

And before you ask, no, this is not configurable, otherwise noone would buy Windows Server.

However, if you want to use WAMPServer for testing (cause thats what it and XAMPP et al were designed for) then you should not have to many problems. It will cope with the volume of traffic just not 100's of connections at the same time

Comment: What do you suggest then?

Comment: @thisisjaymehta Windows has server versions of the operating system. You'll find that *most* people doing PHP in production use a Linux server in production, though.